# user upload multiple pics for avatar approval

Tags: 7, files, media

How to let user upload multiple pics for avatar approval in Drupal 7.

1) I used the [avatar approval](https://www.drupal.org/project/avatarapproval) module, but I want to upload multiple images for different user??

2) Different user can login from own profile and upload our images.

Comment: `...and upload our images.` you mean their images?